# Servicemix bundle breaks when upgrading to Java 8 v311

Tags: java, java-8, preferences, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I am trying to upgrade the version of java being used on my machine from Java 8 v282 to Java 8 v311. When I do upgrade to 311 a servicemix bundle will no longer load correctly. The stack trace of when the bundle failed to load said

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

and it pointed at the following code causing the error:

```
Preferences x = Preferences.systemNodeForPackage(test.class);
String pass = new String(x.getByteArray("fakeKey", null));
```

Is this getByteArray() function deprecated in java 8 v311, because it was working with v282?

Comment: That just means that `fakeKey` can't be resolved to a byte array.

Comment: It seems likely that it isn't the Java version.  It seems that your `Preferences` isn't returning a value and you're trying to construct a String from null.

Comment: Thank you for the answer stdunbar. I believe you are correct, the systemNodeForPackage() function seems to be returning a different value than it was with java 282. Would the best fix for this be to use a different function to retrieve the system preference node?

Comment: I think that would be a blind alley.  The real problem is that your preferences are not set up properly.  If there is no key in the preferences called "fakeKey" or if its value is not a byteArray, then the javadocs state clearly that `x.getByteArray("fakeKey", null)` **should** return `null`.